# Latex code in Markdown

Tags: equations, markdown

Does somebody know how to write this kind of equation in Markdown?

[image]

Comment: Same as in latex, look up the `cases` env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly observed by the very good user **@dailef** using the enviroment cases (for example). PS: There also others methods (with an array).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
BP(\mathcal{D}_{i}\mathcal{D}_{j})=\begin{cases}
\mathcal{B}_{i}\cdot \mathcal{B}_{j} & \mathcal{C}_{i}=\mathcal{C}_{j}\\
0 & \mathcal{C}_{i}\neq \mathcal{C}_{j}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]